# Present sheet after popover

Tags: swiftui, ios13

I have a button on which I want to present two views, one with popover, one with sheet.
The presentation with sheet I need to be triggered from the content of popover.
Unfortunately this doesn't work, I get the following error:

2020-06-22 16:06:54.498830+0300 actionsheetpopover[66042:605785] Warning: Attempt to present <*TtGC7SwiftUIP13$7fff2c9bdf5c22SheetHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*: 0x7f81a590b9c0>  on <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerV18actionsheetpopover11ContentView*: 0x7f81a5909700> which is already presenting <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*: 0x7f81a0d0b4f0>

Expected behaviour: I press: "Show Popover", a view in popover appears, I press: "Close popover and open modal", popover is closed and the view from sheet is presented.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showPopover = false
    @State var showModal = false
    
    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            self.showPopover = true
        }) {
            Text("Show popover")
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
            Button(action: {
                self.showPopover = false
                self.showModal = true
            }) {
                Text("Close popover and open modal")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            Text("Modal")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to give time to close popover, so try the following

```
Button(action: {
    self.showPopover = false
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
      self.showModal = true
    }
}) {
    Text("Close popover and open modal")
}
```

Comment: this is working, thanks!, but is there another way without "manually" delaying the flow?